# Saving Vim files to certain pathways

Tags: filesystem

My question is regarding how to save files to certain folders, or locations

For example I want to save a file called `c++ learning` to a folder on my desktop called `c++`

So after typing `:w` what do  I follow it with to send that file into that folder?

Comment: See `:help :w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the space:

```
:w c++/c++\ learning
```